# Is an instance created?

Tags: java, if-statement, instance, anonymous

Suppose this if condition:

```java
(ObjectA) request.getParameter("something") != null
```

Will an anonymous instance of `ObjectA` be created?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066218/casting-an-object-of-a-superclass-into-an-object-of-a-subclass-creates-a-new-obj

Comment: Is this `request` `HttpServletRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `request` there is already an instance of `ObjectA` if it is not null. So no new instance will be creared.

Comment: you mean to say that by the above statement we are just accessing object present in request scope.
what If I append `Object b =` before condition?

Comment: there will be crected a reference to the existing instance of the object

Comment: I'm interested to know effects of this on GC process? Like will increase or decrease or no effect, on GC?
in reference to work done by GC.

Comment: GC delete all instances of objects which are not reachable. So the effect of this on GC is that the instance will not delete until you delete your reference. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Thank you.
As object is in request scope so it will not be freed until that request object exists.
so No Effect of this on GC, Right?

Answer (score 0):

No, instance is not created. Even if the method returns some objects, it's just the reference is being cast to `ObjectA`.  The instance would have been created by the `request.getParameter()`.

Elaboration, casting doesn't create new instance. it's just the reference is assigned. Below example display the count. Only one instance is created. hope this helps.

```
class Parent1 { static int j; Parent1(){j++;} }
class Child extends Parent1{ static int i; Child(){i++;}}

// and the code
Parent1 pc = new Child();
System.out.println(Child.i);
System.out.println(Parent1.j);
Child p = (Child) pc;
System.out.println(Child.i);
System.out.println(Parent1.j);
```

Output

```
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: I dont think the object reference returned by `request.getParameter("something")` is being casted , `(ObjectA) request.getParameter("something") != null` is like writing `(ObjectA) true` or `(ObjectA) false`. It should be `if(request.getParameter("something")!=null) {ObjectA Obj1=(ObjectA)request.getParameter("something")}`

Answer (score 0):

Why will an instance of `ObjectA` be created, `(ObjectA)` will simply try to cast the returned value from `request.getParameter("something") != null` to the type `ObjectA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getParameter("something")
```

That returns an Object and you are just casting it to `ObjectA` to check it's type. No instance/object created.

Coming to your actual line of code, you need not a cast there just

```
request.getParameter("something") != null
```

is enough.

Comment: I know that that's why I explicitly type casting it to `Object A`.